# Cannot run spyder which installed on conda environment

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, spyder

I have installed spyder on my anaconda env by using `conda install spyder` , but when i run it by using `spyder` command on the same ev, it shows an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ebj/anaconda3/envs/Image_classification/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/ebj/anaconda3/envs/Image_classification/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 252, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/ebj/anaconda3/envs/Image_classification/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 57, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ebj/anaconda3/envs/Image_classification/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 29, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[image]
[image]
may i know why it is happening?? is there anyway i could fix it?

I think i can run spyder if i install it in the normal way, but it is only happening when i install it on conda env

I hope someone would help me find a solution to run spyder on conda env

Comment: Could you please add to the post the output of `conda list '(lib|qt|spyder)'`? Mainly interested to see the source channels for the packages - i.e., are channels being mixed? Also, please replace screenshot with formatted text.

Comment: yes.. I have updated the question.. please check the screenshots

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this problem please run in a terminal: `sudo apt install libnss3`. Then try to run Spyder again, that should work this time.

Comment: It is not working... I have already installed libnss3..

Comment: is anyone could fix it, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix it, that worked for me at least. My issue is that I initially installed Spyder using the conda-forge channel, and I had the exact same issue. When I uninstalled it and reinstalled it from the anaconda channel, it started working correctly.